# Javascript - Como funcionam os "IF e Else" em conjunto com os "returns"?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou com uma dificuldade de entender, por que às vezes, dependendo do local onde está inserida uma declaração "if" em um determinado bloco de uma função, ela é ignorada. E como utilizar os "retuns", quando se deseja dentro dessa expressões parar, avançar ou retornar uma determinada função ?

Por exemplo:

Nesse código abaixo, tudo acontece, como o previsto, no entanto, o cursor fica travado no input e não avança para outro campo nem com TAB nem clicando, fica travado no focus, agora no próximo exemplo :

```js
function nome_existe() {
 
 if(!valida_nome()) { // caso seja inválido
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 return;
 }
 var nome = document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value;
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 xmlreq.open("GET", "mysqli_select_ajax.php?nome_cad=" + nome, true);
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlreq.readyState == 4 && xmlreq.status == 200){
      document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
   document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;
  }
  if(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder == "Nome já existe!"){
   document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Troca o nome";
  }
 }
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 xmlreq.send(null);
 
}
```

Nesse exemplo eu acrescentei um novo "if" que é ignorado, como essas verificações funcionam ?

```js
function nome_existe() {
 
 if(!valida_nome()) { // caso seja inválido
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 return;
 }
 var nome = document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value;
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 xmlreq.open("GET", "mysqli_select_ajax.php?nome_cad=" + nome, true);
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlreq.readyState == 4 && xmlreq.status == 200){
      document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
   document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;
  }
  if(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder == "Nome já existe!"){
   document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Troca o nome";
  }
 }
/*Esse acréscimo parece ser ignorado, o "else" não funciona*/ 
 if(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder != "Troca o nome"){
  document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus();
 }else{
  document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 }
 xmlreq.send(null);
 
}
```

valida_nome();

```js
function valida_nome(){
 var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|\s)+$/ ;
 if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Nome inválido";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_nome(){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = null;
    }
 return false; 
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: talvez ajude se puser o `valida_nome()` na pergunta

Comment: Se você comentar o `xmlreq.send(null);` (acrescentar um `//` na frente), o `else` funciona?

Comment: vc está validando duas vezes, a primeira no if(valida_xxx) lá tem um return false ou true e ao entrar o no if você coloca um return. quando se coloca um return sem nada após ele fica como return true, então independente da sua validação inicial se entrar no if sempre será true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suas condições estão sendo executadas antes da requisição terminar.

O único que você precisa fazer é mover essas condições para o bloco da condição de onde a requisição termina (ex, `if(xmlreq.readyState === 4...)...`). Eu até reformulei só um pouco do código.

```
function nome_existe() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input_nome_cad")
    if (!/^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|\s)+$/.test(input.value)) {
        input.value = ''
        input.placeholder = "Nome inválido"
        input.style.borderColor = "#f00"
        input.style.outline = "#f00"
        input.onkeydown = function() {
            this.style.borderColor = "#999"
            this.style.outline = null
        }
        input.focus()
        return
    }
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest
    request.open("GET"
           , "mysqli_select_ajax.php?nome_cad=" + input.value
           , true)

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                input.value = ''
                if (request.response === "Nome já existe!") {
                    input.placeholder = "Troca o nome"
                    input.focus()
                }
                else {
                    input.placeholder = request.response
                    document.getElementById("input_email_cad").focus()
                }
            }
            else {
                /* Erro de requisição. */
            }
        }
    }
    request.send()
}
```